How to pick right interfaces to use as bond slaves configured as LACP at switches
I have a Linux server with several NICs. Some of its interfaces are connected to LACP PortChannel'ed Cisco ports, but actual connection is unknown.
Is there a way to make sure which exact interface belongs to which PortChannel?
Are there automation tools to make bonded interfaces?
